# Laravel - TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken because of upload filesize

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have found that i need to change these settings in order to upload bigger files

I have changed these settings in my php.ini file

```
upload_max_filesize = 32M
max_file_uploads = 20
```

and this in my nginx.conf file

```
client_max_body_size 40m;
```

but i still get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 27772457 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

This is 8MB limit....but where...i have restarted my machine and it still doesn't work

Where else can i adjust the file upload limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your php.ini you should also change your

```
post_max_size
```

and make it larger than your `upload_max_filesize`

for exemple i use :

```
post_max_size = 125M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

then restart php-fpm

Comment: i still get the same error....it's like it doesn't use php.ini.....i am using php artisan serve command

Comment: OK i found it....i have made all the changes in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini:` instead of `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini:` there are 2 php.ini files actually

Comment: You will get TokenMismatchException if you try to upload the bigger file than it's limited in php.ini

Comment: Now i want to know how to prevent this.....even if i set the validation rule for max file size i still get the tokenmissmatchexception if the file size is more than post_max_size